# How to test disabled attribute of a button?

Tags: html, unit-testing, jestjs, puppeteer, stenciljs

I have a simple **stencil** component like this:

```js
@Component({
  tag: 'app-filled-button',
  styleUrl: 'filled-button.css',
  shadow: true,
})
export class FilledButton {
  @Prop() disabled: boolean;

  render() {
    return (
      <button disabled={this.disabled}>
        <slot></slot>
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

In runtime, this works fine.
But I want to test if the `button` is effectively disabled when the component's prop is set to true:

```js
describe('testing filled button component', () => {
    let page: SpecPage;
    let host: HTMLElement;

    beforeEach(async () => {
        page = await newSpecPage({
            components: [FilledButton],
            html: '<app-filled-button disabled="true"></app-filled-button>'
        });

        host = page.body.querySelector('app-filled-button');
    });

    it('should be disabled', async () => {
        const button = host.shadowRoot.querySelector('button');
        expect(button.disabled).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

With the debugger, I notice that the prop is effectively set to `true` but the HTML attribute is `undefined`. How can I check that attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SpecPage` in spec unit tests limits you to the HTML interface. You can only test what exists in the rendered DOM, not any other properties of a component. So if the component's `Prop` is not reflected as an attribute, you can't access it using `SpecPage`. You can force a `Prop` to be reflected - if it is a string, number, or boolean - using `@Prop({ reflect: true })`. But you may not want to do that - particularly booleans like `disabled` which would then appear as `disabled="false"` etc. It's not something you should do just so you can test it via `SpecPage` - you should do it only if your component is intended to do that.

In e2e tests you can use E2EPage which gives you access to the component's properties as well as attributes. For example:

```
const page = await newE2EPage({ ... });
const component = await page.find('app-filled-button');
const disabled = await component.getProperty('disabled');
```